# Is this possible in QT that we raise signal for a ui form without it's class

Tags: user-interface, qt, qt4, editor, custom-controls

We are developing a UI application wherein we would be giving the users a customised QT designer. The users would then create forms using drag and drop functionality which generates a regular .ui file for the form. The user would link some functionalities with signals, like button press, checkbox select, etc.

There would be a daemon process on the machine which would get some data from somewhere.

Now the question is can the daemon process invoke the appropriate signal in the specified in the UI file, the condition is that no UI file is associated with c++ / header file.

If not how to do it using UIC.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QUILoader](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/quiloader.html) is your friend :

> The QUiLoader class enables standalone
>   applications to dynamically create
>   user interfaces at run-time using the
>   information stored in UI files or
>   specified in plugin paths.